# como alinhar os inputs radios no bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/96ra0n8h/

Fiz deste jeito:

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2"> <p>Discordo Totalmente</p>  <p><input type="radio"/></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> <p>Discordo</p> <p><input type="radio"/></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> <p>Não Concordo nem discordo</p> <p><input type="radio"/></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> <p>Concordo</p> <p><input type="radio"/></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> <p>Concordo Totalmente</p> <p><input type="radio"/></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> <p> (Não Aplicável)</p> <p><input type="radio"/></p></div>

</div>
```

**Problema:**
Quando a screen fica no tamanho do desktop, o texto não fica alinhado com os radios.

quero o mesmo efeito que o de table:

```
<tr>
    <td>Muito d</td>
    <td>s</td>
    <td>Nem snem d</td>
    <td>sd</td>
    <td>Muito sd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1 <input type="radio"  /></td>
    <td>2 <input type="radio"  /></td>
    <td>3 <input type="radio"  /></td>
    <td>4 <input type="radio" /></td>
    <td>5 <input type="radio"/> </td>
    <td>0 <input type="radio" /></td>
</tr>
```

o texto e o input está desalinhado

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qBf90WP.png]

Gostaria de deixar alinhado assim:
  [image: http://i.imgur.com/qBf90WP.png]

Comment: As duas imagens estão iguais...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Editei seu código, veja se aplica a sua necessidade:

http://jsfiddle.net/96ra0n8h/2/

Atualizei o código acima. Atente-se a `media query` que eu criei para dispositivos ou telas acima de `768px`.

Esse código CSS pode colocar no **`bootstrap.css`** que você tem aí ou criar outro arquivo `.css`... você que sabe.

### CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .p-1{
        height: 50px; 
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .p-2{
        vertical-align: bottom; 
        line-height: 50px;
    }
}

<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p class="p-1">Discordo Totalmente</p>
    <p class="p-2"><input type="radio"></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p class="p-1">Discordo</p>
    <p class="p-2"><input type="radio"></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p class="p-1">Não Concordo nem discordo</p>
    <p class="p-2"><input type="radio"></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p class="p-1">Concordo</p>
    <p class="p-2"><input type="radio"></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p class="p-1">Concordo Totalmente</p>
    <p class="p-2"><input type="radio"></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p class="p-1">(Não Aplicável)</p>
    <p class="p-2"><input type="radio"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: funcionou, mas o problema é quando a tela fica no modo mobile: tudo que é texto fica mais acima e todos os radios ficam abaixo, ou seja, ficaram separados.

Comment: Foi o que imaginei que fosse acontecer, expliquei no post. Mas vou tentar ver outra alternativa.

Comment: Dá pra elaborar outra marcação pra mobile para tipo uma _list_ e ocultar essa dos _radios_. Mas não vou fazer, fica pro Diego. :P

Comment: Ah pode fazer... 17 horas tô vazando fi... @KaduAmaral

Comment: kkkk tenho outras coisas pra fazer, bem chatas por sinal, só estou dando um tempo aqui pra esfriar a cabeça. rsrs

Comment: Pronto, fiz: http://jsfiddle.net/96ra0n8h/2/